# Is it possible to have a form that has two submit buttons that go to separate form processing pages?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that currently goes to a PHP page to process the data from the form and output it to plain text. However, I would also like an option to have the output use special HTML formatting. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `formaction`-attribute on the button like this:

```
<form method="post" action="show-as-text.php">

    <button>Show as text</button>
    <button formaction="show-as-html.php">Show as html</button>

</form>
```

The `formatction`-attribute on the button will override the forms `action`.

Comment: I would use inputs for the buttons however... `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`
  `<input type="submit" formaction="/action_page2.php" value="Submit to another page">` this ensures your buttons are set as submit type...

Comment: @dalelandry -  _"this ensures your buttons are set as submit type"_ - So does having a button like the above as well, since "submit" is the default type for `<button>`'s. If you, for what ever reason, don't think that's enough you can just add `type="submit"`, even though it isn't necessary. As it says in the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element) for the `type`-attribute for buttons: _"The missing value default and invalid value default are the Submit Button state."_